# invalid literal for int() with base 10: '' django

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-models, django-templates

template.html

```
<tr id="head-{{ report_person.report_person.id}}">
   <td style="width:150px;"><input type="button" name="delete"  class="delete_icon" value="{{ report_person.report_person.id}}"/>
  {{report_person.report_person.name }}</td>
<td> {{report_person.info.first_aid}}{{report_person.info.first_aid.label}}</td>
<td>{{report_person.info.sick_bay}}{{report_person.info.sick_bay.label}}</td></tr>
```

urls.py

```
(r'^who/$', 'new_report'),
```

views.py

```
def method(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ReportPersonForm(request.POST)
        if 'delete_id' in request.POST: #To delete added names
            ReportPerson.objects.filter(id=request.POST['delete_id']).delete()
            Actions.objects.filter(id=request.POST['delete_id']).delete()
            InjuredLocation.objects.filter(id=request.POST['delete_id']).delete()
    return render
```

custom confirm popup to delete the added data.

```
<div class="delete_confirm" style="display:none">
    <form  method="post" action="." id="{{ report_person.report_person.id}}">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <h2> Are you sure</h2>
        <br />             
        <div style="width:180px;float:right;margin:20px 5px 0 10px">
            <button type="button" name="delete"  class="delete_icon1" value="{{ report_person.report_person.id}}" />Delete</button>
            <button style="margin-right:10px;" type="button" class="close" name="cancel" class="forward backicon">
                <img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}images/button-icon-ir-back.png" width="12" height="17" alt="" />
            Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
$('.delete_icon1').click(function() {
        var csrf_token = $("#csrf_token").val();
        var id = $(this).attr('value');
        $.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...
            data:{
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrf_token,
                delete_id:id
            },
            type:'POST',
            url: '/report/who/', // the file to call
            cache:false,
            success: function() { // on success..
                window.location.href = window.location;
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

Previously i implemented the delete function by clicking the `delete_icon` class it was working fine.Now i added a delete confirmation popup box before delete.Popup is showing,but on clicking delete button i am not able to delete.The `value="{{ report_person.report_person.id}}"` is not passing in popup box that is the id to delete.If i click delete i am getting this error

```
"ValueError at /report/who/
invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''"
```

in FF console.I want to know how to pass the id (`value="{{ report_person.report_person.id}}"`) from html to template.

Comment: The value of the 'delete' button will be available via `request.POST.get('delete')` in your view. If you're expecting to capture that value as a URL segment, you'll need to pass it in as part of the form's `action` parameter, or in the `url` parameter of the Ajax method (which could come from the form).

Comment: @Brandon i want to perform the delete operation using custom popup box,can you guide me how to do in my application here.

Comment: I would need to see your URL pattern(s) and view in order to give you more advice.

Comment: I updated my template,views.py and urls.py.The table of row is dynamically created and the id for row is mentioned as id="head-{{ report_person.report_person.id}}" and id for delete is mentioned in <input type="button" name="delete"  class="delete_icon" value="{{ report_person.report_person.id}}"/>.

Comment: What do you get when you: `console.log(var id = $(this).attr('value'));` ?, which, btw, you can write as: $(this).val();

Comment: I hardcoded the value in popup box and checked,it is deleting the records related to hardcoded value,but dynamically the id what i want to delete is missing,it is showing as empty checked in console.

Comment: I have no idea how you're populating the values in the delete_confirm div form....are those set via JavaScript? or when the page is loaded? Are you sure there's a value in delete button? Have you checked via Firebug?

Comment: If i am using with out popup box it is working fine i am getting the correct id in post and it is deleting the record.I am getting the error after written a popup box.

Comment: How are you creating the popup box?

Comment: No Brandon,i am not getting the values for delete button.I hardcoded the value and tested,it was working.So if i get the value in delete button it will be ok,can you help me,as i have no idea how to get the id to delete button

Comment: Popbox is hidden in page load and it will be active on clicking the delete symbol that is <input type="button" name="delete"  class="delete_icon" value="{{ report_person.report_person.id}}"/>.Popup is not created dynamically,it is static

Comment: Dude, I'm trying to help, but I have no idea how you're creating this popup box and populating the values. If you're adding that box via JavaScript, you won't be able to populate the values of the form elements using Django template tags. You would have to add them via JavaScript. Sounds like the problem is on the client-side, not the Django side.

Comment: Thanks, spared your time to help,Problem is with template logic,i found the solution.It is working fine now.Thanks

Comment: Cool. You should answer your own question to help others when you're able to.